# Include three images, so that the first one spans over two rows

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx

So I would like to have 3 images; the first image spanning across the two other images (the first one is taller than the other two).

Example:

[1]|[2]

[1]|[3]

Here is the code I currently use, keep in mind I am using the `subcaption`-environment and therefore cannot use `subfig` due to conflicts so a `subfloat` is not an option in my case.

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
        \multirow{2}{*}{
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{routes_search.png}
            \caption{Weergave gezochte routes}
            \label{fig:weather_activity}
        \end{subfigure}
        }
         & 
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{weather_filter1.png}
        \caption{Detail van een route}
        \label{fig:weather_filter1}
        \end{subfigure} \\
        &
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{weather_filter2.png}
        \caption{Detail van een route}
        \label{fig:weather_filter2}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \\
        \hline

\end{tabularx}
\caption{Many figures}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would simply use `minipage`s like it is seen so often on TeX.SX.

[image: eniasSubfloats]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.9\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-golden-upright}
                \caption{Weergave gezochte routes}
                \label{fig:weather_activity}
            \end{subfigure}
        \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.9\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Detail van een route}
            \label{fig:weather_filter1}
        \end{subfigure} \\
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.9\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Detail van een route}
            \label{fig:weather_filter2}
        \end{subfigure} 
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Many figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```