# Captioning images within a table

Tags: tables, captions, subfloats

I'd like to group three images and their overall caption together that span over two rows, but asymetrically - essentially like a table where the top row has two of the images and the second row has one image and the caption which are all aligned:

[image]

I can do this using brute force and make a manual caption, but ideally would like to include a proper caption command since this is incorporated in a document with lots of figures. Is there a way to place a caption inside a cell within the tabular environment? Or should this be done in another way? I notice that the [minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310899/include-three-images-so-that-the-first-one-spans-over-two-rows) or [subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64038/table-of-images-with-captions) methods might be useful, but the layout in these thread aren't exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways. In the first one, I have placed 4 minipages insode of a figure environment. In the second example, I have placed the images and their caption inside of a `tabularx` and used the commands from the `cellspace` package to add a uniform white space around the images.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%% Only used for the second example %%%%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{Y}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\tabcolsep}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
    \caption{my caption text goes here my caption text goes here}
    \label{label}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}S{Y}S{Y}@{}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
& \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} \\ 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
& \caption{my caption text goes here my caption text goes here}\label{label} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with the `\RawCaption` command from `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\raggedright
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,valign = c]{example-image-a} \qquad
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,valign = c]{example-image-b}\vspace{4ex}\par

\includegraphics[scale=0.5,valign = c]{example-image-c}\qquad
\parbox{6cm}%
{\hfill\RawCaption{\caption{Three images and the caption aligned like a table}\label{3images}}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]